# How to parse data from the firebase database to int

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

```cs
public void saveData()
{
    Reference.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("level").SetValueAsync(levelText.text.ToString());
}

public void loadData()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("").ValueChanged += Script_ValueChanged;
}

private void Script_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    levelText.text = e.Snapshot.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("level").GetValue(true).ToString();
}
```

In this example I can load my level from the database and save it. My problem right now is I want to load the level from the database and store it in a Int level Variable so I can make a levelup function and update the level in the database. Does someone know how to do that?

```cs
private void Script_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    level = (int)e.Snapshot.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("level").GetValue(true);
    levelText.text = level.ToString();
}
```

my idea was maybe doing it in that way, but inside unity It gives me an error message at that line:
"System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: You cannot cast a string to an int. You can use `Int32.TryParse()` or `Int32.Parse()` for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0 This has nothing to do with Firebase or Unity, though, it's just C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the `int` from the `string`, because a `string` cannot be cast to an `int`. You can use `int.Parse()` for that if you know that it contains a valid integer:

```cs
private void Script_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    level = int.Parse(e.Snapshot.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("level").GetValue(true));
    levelText.text = level.ToString();
}
```

Documentation for `int.Parse()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0

Alternatively, you can also use `int.TryParse()` if you're not 100% certain that the string contains a valid integer:

```cs
private void Script_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(int.TryParse(e.Snapshot.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("level").GetValue(true), out int parsedInt))
    {
        level = parsedInt;
    }
    levelText.text = level.ToString();
}
```

Documentation for `int.TryParse()`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0

Another solution would be to use `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.Parse()`, but it will do the same thing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-7.0

Comment: I got an error with int.Tryparse because I think the data from the database is just an object which can not be converted with int.TryParse, so I just tried it out with Convert.ToInt32 which was fine :) Thanks.

Edit: i wanted to paste the new code but it looked really ugly here, I just changed the int.TryParse to Convert.ToInt32

Comment: You can always cast `object` to `string`, if the underlying type is a `string`. You can also do it with type checking, e.g.: `if(someObject is string myString) {...}`. `Convert.ToInt32()` is also a valid option, I'll add that to the answer.